# proper way of adding/removing classes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a React newbie and have a question!

Im posting this because I haven't been able to find a clear answer on what the best method is for adding/ removing classes to HTML in React. I have created my first React app and came to the point where I wanted to start animating some of the elements of my app by adding/ removing classes when a certain action happens.

Here is what I have done:

I have passed the elements class that I want to animate through a state. The state is given an initial value like so:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
       cartClasses:"order-wrap"
       }
}
```

Then I have passes down the state to a child component which receives the state and implements the cart classes like so:

```
<div className={this.props.cartClasses}>
```

In one of my functions I have the following if statement:

```
 newTotalClean != 0 ? this.setState({cartClasses:"order-wrap cart-out"}) : this.setState({cartClasses:"order-wrap"});
```

Basically it evaluates one of my variables called newTotalClean and if it doesn't equal 0 it updates the state of cartClasses to "order-wrap cart-out" thus adding an extra class that contains CSS animation effects.

Usually I would use jQuery Add/removeClass() but i'm trying to restrict myself from using that and do it in a more React way, not sure if storing classes in a state is the best method or not?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`. Instead of setting the `className`, you set the transition name like the following:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
    transitionName="example" 
    transitionEnterTimeout={500} 
    transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
>
    ... some code here ..
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

See [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) to learn more about Animations in React.

Comment: this is probably the closest to being the standard 'React' way of doing it. Would you say my method is incorrect or an OK workaround?

Answer (score 2):

this is what I usually do. I make a variable that holds the class names and put this variable inside my jsx. Something along the lines of:

```
magic: function() {
  var myClass = this.state.cartClasses;

  if (condition) {
    this.setState({ cartClasses: 'class1' });
  } else {
    this.setState({ cartClasses: 'class2' });
  }  

  return (
    <div className={myClass}>
      hello world
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript utility called classnames which can be used to join multiple classnames.

This is a [link](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) to their github page
This gives more clarity and I have found it more intuitive to understand.
For example, your code could be written as

```
var cartClasses = classNames('order-wrap',{'cart-out':  newTotalClean!=0});
```

The above says that by default,there will be a class called order-wrap assigned and only if the condition is met,the other class is assigned.